# Knockout filter json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, knockout.js

I have some question regarding separating json data on knockout.

Here is the example of the json data.

```
var data = [{"ID":"84F37B0F28374A2B813650079DF45697","LogicalName":"TM1.Application","Name":"Key Performance Indicators (KPIs)","ColumnValue":"blabla."},
{"ID":"C49C30D66E834344B57C18E8693B2A55","LogicalName":"TM1.Cube","Name":"KPI","ColumnValue":"KPI"},
{"ID":"45A8A5F9074644728DFE7901626212E6","LogicalName":"TM1.Process","Name":"Data.KPI.LoadKPIFromAssets","ColumnValue":"blabla."}];
```

Is it possible to separate the data into a different model. What I want to accomplish at the end is to be able to separate the href based on the logicalName.

For example below, where the cubesingle and Cube will depend on the LogicalName returned.

```
<td data-bind="text: $data.LogicalName"></td>
<td><a data-bind="attr: { href: './Documentation/Model Documentation/cubesingle.html?api==Cube('+$data.ID()+')' }, text: $data.Name"></a></td>                                
<td data-bind="text: $data.ColumnValue"></td>
```

Here is the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3c0aaq07/1/

I can do it using knockout foreach. But I want to know if I can split the data first before going to knockout.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this approach.

Html Page

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container1"></div>
        <div id="container2">
            <table>
                <!-- ko foreach: myItems -->
                <tr>
                    <td data-bind="text: $data.LogicalName"></td>
                    <td>
                        <a data-bind="attr: { href: './Documentation/ModelDocumentation/cubesingle.html?api==Cube('+$data.ID()+')' }, text: $data.Name"></a>
                    </td>
                    <td data-bind="text: $data.ColumnValue"></td>
                </tr>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </table>
        </div>


        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/knockout.js"></script>
        <script src="js/DataFunction.js"></script>
        <script src="js/MasterViewModel.js"></script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

MasterViewmodel.js

```
    function MasterViewmodel()
    {
      var self = this;
      var item = function(ID, Name, Description){
        var $this = this;
        self .ID = ko.observable(ID);
        self .LogicalName = ko.observable(LogicalName);
        self .Name = ko.observable(Name);
        self .ColumnValue = ko.observable(ColumnValue);
      }
      self.myItems = ko.observableArray();

      self.UpdateYourTable = function () {
        $.support.cors = true;
        $.getJSON(**yourURL**)
        .done(function (succesdata) {
                if (succesdata!= null) {
                    secondVM.SetJasonData(succesdata);

                }
            })
        .fail(function (xhr, status, error) {
            //console.log(xhr);
            //console.log(status);
            //console.log(error);
        });
    };
    self.UpdateYourTable();
    }
```

Then after master view model is registering as separate viewmodels in DataFunction.js

```
var masterVM;
var secondVM;
$(document).ready(function() {

    if ($.isEmptyObject(masterVM)) {
        masterVM= new MasterViewmodel();
        ko.applyBindings(masterVM, document.getElementById("container1"));
    }
    if ($.isEmptyObject(secondVM)) {
        secondVM= new SecondViewmodel();
        ko.applyBindings(secondVM, document.getElementById("container2"));
        //Here we are registering a new view model for container2 div
    }

});
```

SecondVeiwModel.js

```
function SecondViewmodel()
{
    var self = this;

    self.SetJasonData = function(data){
        //Do what ever you want to do with jason data here
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(data, function(itemData) {
              self.myItems.push(new item (
              itemData.ID ,
              itemData.LogicalName ,
              itemData.Name ,
              itemData.ColumnValue 
           ));
        });
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you to solve your problem.

Comment: The answer still did not separate the data into a separate model.

Comment: Are you using multiple view models?

Comment: Yes I am using multiple view models.

Comment: Please see the edited answer. Register 2 viewmodels and shared data between them.Hope this will work for you.